# Response Handling equivalent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prototype

response.rjs() =>   Evaluates the entire response as Javascript, as is required for Rails RJS responses.

response.execute(fn) => Calls the function object passed to it.

.on(responseStatus) =>Only execute the response function when the status code returned by the server in response to the AJAX request is `responseStatus`. 
But what will be the equivalent it in jQuery-

```
POST(this.up('form').action, data);
response.rjs().on(200);
response.execute(function () { 
  qPanel.hidePanel();
}).on(200);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have convert code of library application_handle-min.js into ujs and issue resolved.